# Person Class Not Outputting Desired Code

Tags: objective-c, lldb

I'm new to objective c programming and my program below produces, "lldb" but i'm not sure why. I've tried messing around a little but nothing has really helped. Can anyone offer some help please?

```
 #import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface Person: NSObject {

    //Field variables
    int weight;
    int age;
}

//The methds along with their return type and arguments (if they need them)
-(void) print;
-(void) setWeight: (int) w;
-(void) setAge: (int) a;
@end

@implementation Person

-(void) print {
    NSLog(@"My age is %i and I weigh %i", age, weight);
}

-(void) setWeight: (int) w {
    weight = age;
}

-(void) setAge: (int) a {
    age = a;
}
@end

int main( int argc, char *argv[]) {

    @autoreleasepool {
        Person *pav;

        pav = [[Person alloc] init];

        [pav setWeight: 145];
        [pav setAge: 19];
        [pav print];
    }

    return 0;

}
```

Comment: Please post the stacktrace.

Comment: @trojanfoe on the left side it said this "argc int 1 1
argv char ** 0x7fff5fbff928 0x00007fff5fbff928"  but i'm not quite sure if this is what you were asking for

Comment: Run the project in Xcode. Wait until it hits the breakpoint and type `bt` in the debugger console and add the output to your question.

Comment: @trojanfoe (lldb) bt
* thread #1: tid = 0xb5e8, 0x0000000100000de6 main`main(argc=1, argv=0x00007fff5fbff928) + 22 at main.m:33, queue = 'com.apple.main-thread', stop reason = breakpoint 3.1
  * frame #0: 0x0000000100000de6 main`main(argc=1, argv=0x00007fff5fbff928) + 22 at main.m:33
(lldb)

Comment: OK, add an exception breakpoint and try again. https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-breakpoint_navigator/articles/adding_an_exception_breakpoint.html